# Interesting way to integrate a function with two variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My question came up with this differential Equation:

$$(x + y)(\Bbb dx-\Bbb dy) = \Bbb dx+\Bbb dy$$

I've seen a lot of indian people in Youtube doing integration like this (i'll show you while i'm solving the ODE):

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb dx - \Bbb dy &= \frac{\Bbb dx + \Bbb dy}{x + y}\\
x - y &= \ln(x+y) + c
\end{align}$$

That implies:
$$\int \frac{\Bbb dx + \Bbb dy}{x + y} = \ln(x+y) + c$$

But how? How does it make sense? I'm trying to split the integral but i got this:

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\Bbb dx + \Bbb dy}{x + y} &= 
\int \frac{\Bbb dx}{x + y} + \int \frac{\Bbb dy}{x + y}\\
&= \ln(x+y) + \ln(x+y)\\
&= 2\ln(x+y)
\end{align}$$

Honestly i still can't process this. But i've verified with an implicit differentation that the solution satisfies the ODE.

Comment: $dx - dy = d(x - y)$ and $\dfrac{dx + dy}{x + y} = \dfrac{d(x+y)}{x+y}$

Comment: @BobaFret still don't understand. Maybe you can post the answer for more details please.

Comment: @BobaFret i mean yes i can logically treat them as a one variable. But how does it make sense?

Comment: @user516076 what is the problem changing variables under the ntegral to $u=x+y$ to get $$\int \frac{d(x+y)}{x+y} = \int \frac{du}{u} = \ln|u| + C = \ln|x+y| + C$$

Comment: @gt6989b Yes. Sorry for my retardness. I mean for treating $\Bbb du = \Bbb dx + \Bbb dy$, is what? Is that a total derivative or what? I've seen a different form for total derivative that looks like the sum of differential that cancel each other. But it's not like that?

Comment: It is just a change of variable. You can change variables in multi-dimensional integrals as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the difficulty of understanding comes from a change of variables.
$$(x+y)(dx-dy)=dx+dy$$
So we will detail all steps of the change of variables :
$$\begin{cases}
X=x-y\\
Y=x+y
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}
dX=dx-dy \\
dY=dx+dy
\end{cases}$$
Puting them into the original equation :

[image]
$$Y\:dX=dY$$
This is an elementary separable ODE which solution is well known :
$$Y=c\:\exp(X)$$
$$x+y=c\:e^{x-y}$$
This is the solution expressed on the form of an implicit equation.

One cannot solve this implicit equation for $y(x)$ in terms of a finite number of elementary functions. One have either to expand into infinite series or to use a special function namely the Lambert W function.

For information the manner to get the explicit solution is :
$$(x+y)e^{x+y}=c\:e^{x-y}e^{x+y}=c\:e^{2x}$$
Let $z=x+y$ and $t=c\:e^{2x}$
$$ze^z=t\quad\implies\quad z=W(t)$$
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

$$x+y=W(c\:e^{2x})$$
$$y(x)=-x+W(c\:e^{2x})$$

Comment: Wonderful answer. Can you tell me more about how $X=x-y\Rightarrow dX=dx-dy$? Is that a total derivative or what? And as we know the partial derivative must the derivative of one of the variables, but again what's about $dX = dx - dy$??

Comment: $$dF(x,y)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy$$ Case $F=x-y\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=1 \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=-1$ $$d(x+y)=1*dx+(-1)*dy=dx-dy$$ .

Comment: i understand. Thanks for the explanation!